# C++ std::vector emplace vs insert

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I was wondering what are the differences between the two. I notice that emplace is c++11 addition. So why the addition ?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Emplace takes the arguments necessary to construct an object in place, whereas insert takes (a reference to) an object.

```
struct Foo
{
  Foo(int n, double x);
};

std::vector<Foo> v;
v.emplace(someIterator, 42, 3.1416);
v.insert(someIterator, Foo(42, 3.1416));
```

Comment: Although the question is marked duplicate, this answer clarifies things for me MUCH better then the answers to the "original".

Answer (score 54):

`insert` copies objects into the vector.

`emplace` *construct* them inside of the vector.

Comment: Note that in C++11 `insert` does not have to copy, it can also move.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that while insert may move if it an rvalue cast is used, it may not. Hence, Scott Meyer's recommendation to use emplace whenever possible for performance clarity.