# What is the difference between std::list::insert() and std::list::emplace()

Tags: c++, stdlist, emplace

What is the difference between std::list::insert() and std::list::emplace()? I need to pass a value to either of them. I had expected emplace to create an instance of the list's data type without initializing it with some value I pass but just construct it, because the documentation says that it constructs a new element in place.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788261/c-stdvector-emplace-vs-insert https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303513/push-back-vs-emplace-back

Comment: So the only difference is that I can pass a variadic list of arguments to emplace? Meh. That could have just as well been done with an overload of insert().